# Python (PyQt5) При нажатии на кнопку pushButton не срабатывает функция buttonClicked

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, gui, pyqt

Python (PyQt5) начал изучать не так давно. Подскажите пожалуйста, почему при нажатии на кнопку `pushButton` в изначально пустой метке `label` не появляется надпись "111" (не срабатывает функция `buttonClicked`? Юзаю Python 3.8.

**ButtonLabel.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(428, 219)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 90, 211, 71))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")


        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 20, 201, 31))
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 428, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Hello World!!!"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**HelloWorld.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import QWindow

from ProjectButtonLabel.ButtonLabel import Ui_MainWindow


class MainWindow(QWindow,Ui_MainWindow):  
    def __init__(self, parent=None, *args, **kwargs):  
        QWindow.__init__(self)  
        self.setupUi(self)
       

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.buttonClicked)

    def buttonClicked(self, text):
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label.setText("111")
        self.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы немного перестарались. Спросите если что-то будет не понятно.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
#? from PyQt5.QtGui import QWindow


#from ProjectButtonLabel.ButtonLabel import Ui_MainWindow
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(428, 219)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 90, 211, 71))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 20, 201, 31))
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 428, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Hello World!!!"))
        

#class MainWindow(QWindow, Ui_MainWindow):  
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow): 
#    def __init__(self, parent=None, *args, **kwargs):  
#        QWindow.__init__(self)  
    def __init__(self):                                         # +
        super().__init__()                                      # +
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.buttonClicked)

    def buttonClicked(self):                                    # - , text):
#?        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label.setText("<h1>Hello World</h1>")
#?        self.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
#    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
#    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
#    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
#    MainWindow.show()
    w = MainWindow()                                  # +++
    w.show()                                          # +++
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @TRAMPlin30 все ли вам понятно?

Comment: Спасибо огромное!! Исправил. Все работает. Я так понял не было доступа к переменным и методам в файле ButtonLabel.py родительского класса Ui_MainWindow, который наследуется классом MainWindow в файле HelloWorld.py? Так?

Comment: @TRAMPlin30 вы не создавали объект класса `class MainWindow(QWindow, Ui_MainWindow):`, а создавали   объект `MainWindow` - `MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()` , в котором нет того что вы хотели сделать: `self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.buttonClicked)`, `def buttonClicked(self):`, ... Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour